# docstring codeblock not showing properly in spyder

Tags: python, spyder, docstring

I am trying to create an block of example code for a python module that I have written, according to [here](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/help.html) spyder uses sphinx to render the docstring in the help window. When I try to create a code block with:

```
'''
Example:
---------
.. code-block :: python

:: 
    def testing():
        pass
'''
```

Below is what is rendered:
[image]

`testing(): ...` should be inside the highlighted block. I have no idea how to fix this... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out (after a lot of fiddling) that an empty line under `::` is required:

```
'''
Example:
---------
::

    def testing():
        pass
'''
```

Renders properly,
[image]

It seems that `.. code-block :: python` was also causing some problems, I am not sure why.